# Duplicating A SQL Entry Million's Of Times For Scaling Testing

Tags: sql

For one of our more critical projects we need to run our application through some tests sets with extremely large databases. Our normal maximum average is about 100,000 entries, but we're looking to test against approximately 18-24,000,000 entries.

Now I could go into the details of it, but I think it's better for me to ask from a high level: What's the best way to duplicate data to that scale? Is it better to take a small set (3 entries) and duplicate that all the way up to 18,000,000, or should I take an existing db with 100,000 records and duplicate that fewer times?

There does need to be some data editing, in that each entry needs to have a unique GUID in one column and a friendly name in another.

I have a stored procedure that I cleaned up from a ex-co-worker's archive, it takes a record and adds an incrimental number to the end of the two unique columns and then closes and runs again. It takes a like 4 hours to get to 6,000,000 and that's about 14GB I think. We've only ever used it for up to 100,000 records, but it does that rather well.

But with this size it seems like it locks up (SQL Management Studio Crashes), goes really really slow or just does nothing but still acts like it is (No CPU activity). And the log file gets massive, like 20GB for the 14GB database file.

Here is the stored procedure as it is right now:

```
USE [DBNAME]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PERSON_Insert]
@LoopCount int,
@PersonId varchar(50)
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @intFlag INT ,@P_FIELD1 Varchar(50),@T_FIELD2 Varchar(10),@T_FIELD3 numeric(11,0), @T_FIELD4 numeric(11,0), @T_FIELD5 varchar(8000), @T_FIELD6 numeric(20,0)
,@TR_FIELD7 Varchar(10),@TR_FIELD8 numeric(11,0), @TR_FIELD9 numeric(11,0), @TR_FIELD10 varchar(8000), @TR_FIELD11 numeric(20,0)
    SET @intFlag = 1
select @P_FIELD1=dbo.MyRegistratonNo(@PersonId)
select @T_FIELD2=dbo.MyENGINETYPE(@PersonId,1)
select @T_FIELD3=dbo.MyTEMPLATEID(@PersonId,1)
select @T_FIELD4=dbo.MyTEMPLATETYPE(@PersonId,1)
select @T_FIELD5=dbo.MyTEMPLATEFEATURE(@PersonId,1)
select @T_FIELD6=dbo.MyTEMPLATESIZE(@PersonId,1)
select @TR_FIELD7=dbo.MyENGINETYPE(@PersonId,2)
select @TR_FIELD8=dbo.MyTEMPLATEID(@PersonId,2)
select @TR_FIELD9=dbo.MyTEMPLATETYPE(@PersonId,2)
select @TR_FIELD10=dbo.MyTEMPLATEFEATURE(@PersonId,2)
select @TR_FIELD11=dbo.MyTEMPLATESIZE(@PersonId,2)
WHILE (@intFlag <=@LoopCount)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO [PERSON]
([PERSONID],[REGISTRATIONNO] , [TYPEID] , [REGISTEREDDATE] , [STATUS])
VALUES(@PersonId+CAST(@intFlag AS varchar(50)),@P_FIELD1+CAST(@intFlag AS varchar(50)),1,GETDATE(),1)
INSERT INTO [TEMPLATES]
([PERSONID],[ENGINETYPE] , [TEMPLATEID] , [TEMPLATETYPE] , [TEMPLATEFEATURE] , [TEMPLATESIZE])
VALUES(@PersonId+CAST(@intFlag AS varchar(50)),@T_FIELD2,@T_FIELD3,@T_FIELD4,@T_FIELD5,@T_FIELD6)
INSERT INTO [TEMPLATES]
([PERSONID],[ENGINETYPE] , [TEMPLATEID] , [TEMPLATETYPE] , [TEMPLATEFEATURE] , [TEMPLATESIZE])
VALUES(@PersonId+CAST(@intFlag AS varchar(50)),@TR_FIELD7,@TR_FIELD8,@TR_FIELD9,@TR_FIELD10,@TR_FIELD11)
PRINT @P_FIELD1 +CAST(@intFlag AS varchar(50))
SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
END
END
```

There are also some scalar-functions, six of which are used and all follow the same format:

```
USE [DBNAME]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MyENGINETYPE]
(@PersonID varchar(50),@TemplateID numeric(11,0))
RETURNS varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Return varchar(10)
SELECT @Return = (SELECT ENGINETYPE FROM TEMPLATES WHERE PERSONID=@PersonID AND TEMPLATEID=@TemplateID)
RETURN @Return
END
```

Keep in mind I'm an light scripter/webdev, not really a dba or good at enterprise-class data like this. That being said is this at least a decent way to go at it, or am I murdering this server with something clunky? We've only the SQL Server 2012, no third-party tools or anything outside of what comes with it and we would like to keep it that way.

Any examples would be amazing, thanx in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

This may give you some ideas.

`SET NOCOUNT ON` is important to stop the 'inserted 1 row' messages.

Also might be worth looking at disabling / deleting indexes before the insert - might speed things up.

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
    PersonId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID() PRIMARY KEY,
    Blah1 VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT REPLICATE('X', 50)
)
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

DECLARE @i INT
SET @i = 1

WHILE (@i <= 1000000)
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO Person DEFAULT VALUES 
   SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

Another option would be to create a flat file, and use bulk insert.  It may take some effort to create the flat file but should be a one off - unless you need to change the data.